# how exactly package.json update flag work (under the hoods)

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I'm trying to understand how the package.json update process work. For example:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4",
},
```

In this case I have Express with the minus flag `^` for only 4.X.X update. This is clear. But exactly how this update work? I mean, if I delete the `node_module` folders (and the package-lock.json) 1 weeks after the first installation (and a new Express version is released) which version I download? The 4.16.4 or (for example) the 4.17.0? I think the 4.17.0 but the package.json still remain with the 4.16.4 (text description) and the update is reported in the package-lock.json or something else? I've never seen the numbers change in the package.json.

I am very confused about this.

Sometimes, when I check some module from their folder I see a different version from the package.json. Why?

Comment: did my answer make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caret (^) will update to the **most recent major version** (the first number). `^4.16.4` will match any `4.x.x` release including `4.17.x`, but will hold off on updating to the version `5.0.0.` release of `Express` since this is a major release with breaking change to the `Express` library.

As for your question: *"If I were to delete the `node_modules` directory and the `package-lock.json` file a week after first installing `Express` and say a new `Express` version was release in that timeframe. Which version of `Express` would I download?*

That depends if the newest version was a **major**, **minor,** or **patch** release. If the newest version was a minor or patch release: *second or third number changes*, then *npm would install the latest 4.x.x. `Express` version.* In your specific example scenario, yes it would install `Express` *V4.17.0*. You're also correct that the `package.json` will still list `"express: "^4.16.4"` as a necessary dependency to build your project. This is because of how the **caret works, as explained earlier: grab the latest 4.x.x. version of `Express`**. There is no need to update your `Express` listing within the `package.json` to the newest version since the carrot will take care of that for you. If you think about it, that is a really nice feature since the alternative would be to *manually specify each new version release* even if it is just a minor or patch release. And nobody has time for that... unless it's major release.

Furthermore, since the *latest `Express` release wasn't a major release* i.e. the first number of your `Semver` didn't change there are no "breaking changes" so it's *usually safe* to just grab the latest version. However, with that being said you can specify an exact version of any dependency if desired. As for the `package-lock.json` file, this file is kind of like a "*snapshot*" of your **current configurations and build dependencies**. So this file will update as you make changes that affect the building of your project: i.e *either adding new dependencies or updating existing versions.* This is because this file should be the *"source of truth"* for others in case they wanted to replicate building your project and potentially contributing to it.

Hopefully that helps!